# Gstreamer videomixer Very low framerate

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, frame-rate

I am trying to composite three streams coming from three Rapsberry PI.

As soon as I join two streams together using the videomixer plugin, I get a message ending with:

**Pipeline:pipeline0/GstOSXVideoSink:osxvideosink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.**

Strangely, my task monitor only indicates about 15%CPU usage for gst

With the three streams, the framerate becomes unusable. I would expect my I7 macbook to be able to handle this without problem....

Here is the code I am using for the mixing, in this case just one stream(/sink?). 
Can anyone tell me whether there is an obvious mistake ? Or where I should look for the bottleneck and improve it ?
Thanks !

```
gst-launch-1.0 videomixer name=m sink_1::xpos=400 sink_2::ypos=300 ! autovideosink \
-v udpsrc port=9000 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264'! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264,width=400,height=300,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! m. \
-v udpsrc port=9001 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264,width=400,height=300,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! m. \
-v udpsrc port=9002 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264,width=400,height=300,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert !  m.
```

Here is the code I use to send the streams from the RPI Camera.

```
raspivid -n -w 640 -h 480 -t 0 -o - \
| gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay \ 
config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.3 port=9000
```

Comment: hm what about glvideomixer? I am now not sure how is OpenGL functional on RPI

Comment: Can you paste the code you're using with two streams attached to the mixer?  I don't see any `queue` elements in your pipeline either.

Comment: @otopolsky the videomixer is on Mac, and for some reason glvideomixer is not appearing on my setup. I have searched on how to install it but I cannot find any information about it. I must be looking the wrong direction. Can you by any chance tell me how to get the glvideomixer installed on the Mac (I have installed the plugins base,good,bad,ugly and libav) but no gl elements appear when i do a gst-inspect-1.0

Comment: @mpr Thanks for the reply, I edited the code to reflect the full command.

Comment: maybe when you recompile on mac with some opengl dev packages installed? I dont know how to do it.. maybe ask on #gstreamer freenode IRC..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding queue elements for each video decode and `sync=false` to the video sink.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videomixer name=m sink_1::xpos=400 sink_2::ypos=300 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink sync=false \
udpsrc port=9000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264,width=400,height=300 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! m. \
udpsrc port=9001 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264,width=400,height=300 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! m. \
udpsrc port=9002 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264,width=400,height=300 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert !  m.
```

Now my disclaimer to this would be that I'm unsure if the video will be properly smooth and in sync, but it seems to look pretty good.

Also, on raspivid, you'll probably want to add the `config-interval` property to the `rtph264pay` element.

```
raspivid -n -w 640 -h 480 -t 0 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! multiudpsink clients=192.168.1.3:9000,192.168.1.3:9001,192.168.1.3:9002
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This solution does get rid of the jerkyness in the image and the messages about dropped frames. Unfortunatelly, it also brings a huge delay to the images (around 5 seconds) which is not ok for my purpose. I started to work with gstreamer because of the low latency, which is what I am after.

Comment: I got a hold of a Pi to test with.  Added queues on the receiving end and put a config-interval on the rtph264pay and it seems to perform fine now and handle restarts on either end.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. adding the modifications you suggest does indeed seem to improve the performance. Great !